# How to complete a variable name with another variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object that stores 3 variables called `text0, text1 and text2` that in turn store one string each. I also have a variable that stores the index of the clicked button, so that if I click on the third button it should fetch the `text2`.

**I was trying something like this:**

```
p.text(myObj.text + btnNumber);
```

But so far all I get is **NaN**. Is it even possible to do this way? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use named indexing of the object to get a variable named property:

```
p.text(myObj["text" + btnNumber]);
```

Javascript lets you index properties of an object as if it were a dictionary (indexed via string names).